# How to decrypt a MD5 Password that is exactly 9 digits long?

Tags: md5, password-hash

I have a hash from my school work that I need to decrypt.
The hash is: `68728d8fa7977d2567c6363381eda037`.
It looks like it uses either MD4 or MD5 hashing algorithm

How to decrypt it?

Comment: If you need help, please share your attempts to resolve the problem. Is this related to programming after all?

Comment: The sole idea of a hash is that it's **NOT** possible to reverse it at all. Even with the obsolete MD4 or MD5 the only way to get a possible input string is brute force, and even then you can never be sure it's the correct way. It's simply not possible to do this, by design.

Answer (score 0):

You "decrypt" a hash by making a lookup table. In your case, if you know that the password is exactly 9 digits long, you'd create a hash for every possible 9-digit password and compare each one to the hash you're trying to decrypt.

Comment: and how do i do this?

Comment: @0szi Do you know any programming languages?

Comment: yes i know but i think i need a rainbow table becaues i tried at least 20 online tools and no one gave me a result

Comment: @0szi There is no way to reverse a hash operation, the only way to find a possible preimage is with a rainbow table. All online tools are actually looking at their own table internally and no one happens to have your hash in it. You need to build your own or get a bigger one.

Comment: @0szi Yes, what I'm suggesting is you generate your own (small) rainbow table, with just your range of possible inputs.

Answer (score 0):

By definitions `hash` is one way encryption so you can't decrypt it. You can use kind of tables with all possible combinations. Which is CPU consuming process. Here is one simple code on meta language:

```
for i from 0 to 999999999
h=md5(i)
write(file,h)
endoffor
line=search(file,inputhash)
print(line)
```